# Garbage Collector Questions

Tags: java, garbage-collection

1. I read in a book ( Java Performance: The Definitive Guide” by Scott Oaks" )  that the young gen collector is always stop-the-world and single threaded, no matter which GC algorithm is being used.
   If that is true, why is that young gen collection always takes negligible amount of time compared to old gen collection ?
   Is it because young gen space is small compared to oldgen ?
   ( If yes, how is the time taken for GC related to the amount of heap -  exponential ?)
2. When you have a small value for initial heap size ( -Xms ) and a larger upper limit ( -Xmx ), what happens when the initial limit is reached ?
   Will teh JVM do a full GC or will it grow the heap size till it hits the -Xmx limit ?

Comment: I don't think Java has used a "stop the world" GC in a long time.  You should [read something more current.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/toc.html) (That might not be the best document for you, but it's dated this year and will at least be current.)

Comment: @markspace, you are wrong. all hotspot GCs use STW pauses. At best they're only partially-concurrent.

Comment: @markspace  Book : Java Performance: The Definitive Guide” by Scott Oaks". This book was published in 2014 and the Author is a well known Java Engineer. Also it mentions this multiple times in this book ivery clearly. ( that , Young gen collection is always single
threaded and during this app threads are always stopped - no matter
which GC algorithm is chosen )

Answer (score 3):

> I read in a book that the young gen collector is always stop-the-world, no matter which GC algorithm is being used.

more or less, yes. But except for the SerialGC they're multithreaded, so throwing more cores at the problem makes young collections faster for the same amount of memory.

> If that is true, why is that young gen collection always takes negligible amount of time compared to old gen collection ?

It's not always negligible, there are many factors that go into young generation sizing

> Is it because young gen space is small compared to oldgen ?

to some extent yes, but it's not the size alone, the fraction of live objects also matters. if objects die fast they don't need to be visited/copied.

> If yes, how is the time taken for GC related to the amount of heap - exponential ?

It depends. If we're talking about pause time it's rather complicated. If we're talking about CPU cycles burnt (including concurrent) for a full GC it's roughly linear with the amount of live objects. If we're talking overall CPU cycles (instead of per-GC) it again gets more complicated.

But either way, it's not exponential. The number of CPU cycles spent on garbage collection should generally be a small fraction relative to the CPU cycles spent on application code. But as mentioned above, CPU cycles != pause time.

> When you have a small value for initial heap size ( -Xms ) and a larger upper limit ( -Xmx ), what happens when the initial limit is reached ? Will teh JVM do a full GC or will it grow the heap size till it hits the -Xmx limit ?

Depends on the GC selected and various other settings. I suggest you simply observe a GC in action with [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors (slightly outdated, some of the combinations are deprecated and to be removed in jdk9)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/

This is mostly for oracle/openjdk's hotspot. Other JVMs and other collectors exist. The most interesting alternative being azul's zing which has an effectively [pauseless collector](http://www.azul.com/resources/azul-technology/azul-c4-garbage-collector/)

Comment: I too used to believe that,  except for serial GC, young gen collection is multi threaded. But then I read 'Java Performance : The Definitive Guide'  by Scott Oaks. He mentions clearly in multiple places that the young gen is always single threaded ( no matter which GC algorithm is chosen ), and also that during young GC, app threads are always stopped. This book is of very high quality and he is a very well reputed engineer from Sun. So there is no reason to doubt his claim

Comment: The book is wrong, this can be easily verified by simply looking at GC logs, *which is what I have suggested*. Please look at reality, not your bible. It's also possible that you're misunderstanding what's written.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I looked back to read teh book again. It only says that 'All GC algorithms have stop-the-world pauses during collection of the young generation.'. Also verified that all - except serial GC - will have multiple threads during collecting younggen